# Spark MatrixFactorizationModel crashes on recommendProductsForUsers call

Tags: apache-spark, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I have an implicit MatrixFactorizationModel in Apache Spark 1.6.0 over 3M users and 30k items. Now I would like to compute the top-10 recommended items per user for all the users with something like the following code:

```
val model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "/hdfs/path/to/model")
model.userFeatures.cache
model.productFeatures.cache
val recommendations: RDD[(Int, Array[Rating])] = model.recommendProductsForUsers(10)
```

Unfortunately this crashes the computation with the following error:

```
WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_xxx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxx_xx_xxxxx on host: xxxxx.xxxx.xxx. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_xxx_xxxxx_xxxx_xx_xxxxxxx
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

What is the reason and how can the recommendations be computed?

Spark runs on a 54 node cluster and I start the REPL with:

```
spark-shell  \
--master yarn \
--driver-memory 16g \
--executor-memory 16G \
--num-executors 32 \
--executor-cores 8
```

User and item factors are each in cached RDDs with 504 partitions.